# Starting .exe with process from C# yields different result than running the .exe directly

Tags: process, tfsbuild, startprocessinfo

I have a custom workflow activity that is run in TFS 2010 Build that uses `Process` and `ProcessInfo` classes to start a custom `.exe` that hosts a WCF service for our unit tests.

When the custom .exe is run from my workflow activity that uses `Process` and `ProcessInfo` classes to start it nothing works and my unit tests don't pass. But if I start the process directly using a `.bat` file on the build server all the tests pass fine.

Is there a difference between running a process from the `Process` class in .Net as opposed to running it directly with a .bat file?

Comment: Could be different environment variables, or different working directories? I don't know much about TFS so it's just a guess.

Comment: Who's running the exe? ... I'll let that sink in for a moment.

Comment: When the process is running from TFS build it is running under a service account and that service account is who launches the custom .exe that hosts the WCF Service, but this way does not work.  When I log in to the build server directly, I use the same service account to run the .bat file that runs the custom .exe that hosts the WCF service and this works right every time.

Comment: Please add your findings as an answer and accept it. This will close the question.

Answer (score 1):

I figure out what I had done wrong. When I ran my custom .exe that hosts the WCF service from my .bat file I explicitly did a "cd" to the working dir of the custom .exe. But in my C# custom workflow activity I did not set the working directory on the ProcessInfo type. Once I did that it works perfectly! Thanks for your comments.